# Excel formula for comparison

Tags: excel, function, comparison

This is related to excel formulas, I have numeric values in column A, till A14 and Text in column B till B14, I want to compare numeric values like : If A1 is less than A2 then give me A1 and If A1 is greater than A2 give me A2. I am using IF statement but it gives me result for the 1st instance only wen I am copying the formula, I am not getting the same result. Motive is to compare A1 and A2, then A3 and A4 and so on so that I can get a result with lower numeric values. Later I again want to compare the result like If for the first comparison I get A1 as a result and for second I get A3 as result, I want to compare A1 and A3 then and so on . Can I get some help ?

Comment: Try looking up absolute and relative references. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: i was trying If with Index match and the result was good for the first instance but for others it was not working, dnt know hw to figure out

Comment: You want to chain together a bunch of formulas to find the minimum of a range of 15 cells. Is there a reason you don't just do it in one formula? Your mention of copying formulas makes me wonder if you don't understand relative references. Do you?

Comment: Got u !!! it was something weird i dint block the range. lol thanks for ur time

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Large function in Excel to determine a cell's relative standing. It's a variation on Min and Max.

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/LARGE-function-e5458a3e-c4bd-4126-8e88-5042b838b706?CorrelationId=bf394306-931b-4d82-bf2c-77c7ec23c0e5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US